# LINQ Lambda Join, with 2 join fields or more error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to C#, I try to Groupjoin with more than one fields as the keys using LINQ using Extension methods but with no success.

My Class

```
public class NewStruct
    {
        public string newId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Table2> newTable2 { get; set; }
    }
```

My Code

```
var context = new MyDBContex();

IQueryable<NewStruct> list = context.Table1
    .GroupJoin(context.Table2,
        e => new { e.Id1, e.Id2, e.Datefield },
        q => new {q.Id1, q.Id2, e.Datefield },
    (t1, t2) => new NewStruct { newId= t1.Id1, newTable2 = t2 });
```

this will raise error

```
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Queryable.GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IQueryable<TOuter>, IEnumerable<TInner>, Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>>, Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>>, Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

but, when the condition fild for joining is only one like this

```
IQueryable<NewStruct> list = context.Table1
    .GroupJoin(context.Table2,
        e => e.Id1,
        q => q.Id1,
    (t1, t2) => new NewStruct { newId= t1.Id1, newTable2 = t2 });
```

it's no errors

What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are properties Id1, Id2, Datefield of Table1 and Table2 of the same type? Did you try to use a non-anonymous type containing these three properties as parameter KeySelector in the GroupJoin?

Comment: The error indicates one of the generic type parameters doesn't match like it should, so probably `Func<TOuter,TKey>` doesn't have the same result type as `Func<TInner,TKey>` and so `TKey` can't be inferred.

Comment: thank you for commenting, but all Id is the same type, and when i change may last code that does not generate errors, i try add new keyword like this e => new {e.Id1}, q=> new {q.Id2}, its generates above error, so the new keyword is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the work around, the code should like this,

```
IQueryable<NewStruct> list = context.Table1
    .GroupJoin(context.Table2,
        e => new { id1 = e.Id1, id2 = e.Id2, dt = e.Datefield },
        q => new { id1 = q.Id1, id2 = q.Id2, dt = e.Datefield },
    (t1, t2) => new NewStruct { newId= t1.Id1, newTable2 = t2 });
```

thank you all